# Parse REST api query constraint where createdAt equals yesterday

Tags: django, get, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse.com REST api with Django and am trying to write a GET query were the "createdAt" datetime field equals "yesterday" (date)

I haven't had any issues with other queries but cannot seem to figure out the best approach for querying on createAt.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

**Parse Doc**
https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries-constraints

**My GET query**

```
c = 'where={"createdAt":YESTERDAY GOES HERE}'
resp_trainers = sess.get('https://api.parse.com/1/users', params=c)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify dates as dates, not as strings.
Try

```
'where={"createdAt":{"__type":"Date", "iso":"2014-12-10T00:00:00.000Z"}}'
```